# Can't seem to get the break statement working correctly in conditional and for-loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am looping through a collection of links in the DOM and trying to set an attribute based on a condition. While doing so i'd like to strip out a specific string after the base URL:

```
http://smodev.rye.avon.com/XXXX/page.aspx
```

so I'd get:

```
page.aspx
```

So far I managed to get the base URL off, and at first I thought to use a regex, to zero in on `/XXXX/`, but I'd like to use this script in another context, because at other instances having just the pathname is swell:

```
/XXXX/XXXX/page.aspx
```

Naturally I thought using a `conditional` with the `includes` and `replace` methods in the following would work.

```
  var MarkUpChecker = (function iffe() {
    var publicAPI = {
        getURL: function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
                return {
                    'smo': 'http://smo.rye.avon.com',
                    'smodev': 'http://smodev.rye.avon.com',
                    'youravon_sans_w': 'http://youravon.com',
                    'youravon': 'http://www.youravon.com',
                    'youravon2': 'http://www2.youravon.com'
                }[arguments[i]];
            }
        },
        searchURL: function() {
            var link, url, parser, newPathName = '';
            for (var i = 0, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++) {
                url = this.getURL(arguments[i]);
                for (var j = 0, jlen = document.links.length; j < jlen; j++) {
                    link = document.links[j];
                    if (link.href.indexOf(url) !== -1) {
                        parser = document.createElement('a');
                        parser.href = link.href;

                        link.setAttribute('target', '_self');
                        newPathName = parser.pathname;


                        if (newPathName.includes('/Executive/')) {
                            var newstr = newPathName.replace('/Executive/', '');
                            break;
                        }
                        if (newPathName.includes('/District/')) {
                            newstr = newPathName.replace('/District/', '');
                            break;
                        }
                        if (newPathName.includes('/Division/')) {
                            newstr = newPathName.replace('/Division/', '');
                            break;
                        }
                        if (newPathName.includes('/National/')) {
                            newstr = newPathName.replace('/National/', '');
                            break;
                        }
                        link.href = newstr;

                    }

                }
            }
        }
    };
    return publicAPI;
})();
```

When stepping through the debugger I noticed in the first pass it works! `\0/` However as the loop progresses, It becomes a mess as you can see here:

[image]

Shouldn't the `newstr` variable just return:

```
/XXXX/XXXX/XXXX/page.aspx
```

Otherwise just return

```
page.aspx
```

when it encounters `'/Executive/', '/District/', '/Division/', '/National/'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`break` is not doing what you expect -- it is not like in a `case` statement -- it makes you exit the inner `for` loop!

Secondly, if none of the `if` conditions is true, you assign a `newstr` value that is either `undefined`, or the value set during a previous iteration. That really causes a tremendous mix-up.

Instead use `else`:

```
if (newPathName.includes('/Executive/')) {
    var newstr = newPathName.replace('/Executive/', '');
} else if (newPathName.includes('/District/')) {
    newstr = newPathName.replace('/District/', '');
} else if (newPathName.includes('/Division/')) {
    newstr = newPathName.replace('/Division/', '');
} else if (newPathName.includes('/National/')) {
    newstr = newPathName.replace('/National/', '');
}
```

But looking at what you try to do here, you can do that in one `replace`:

```
var newstr = newPathName.replace('/Executive|District|Division|National/', '');
```

If your goal is to remove the path completely when one of these words occurs, then do this:

```
if(newPathName.search(/Executive|District|Division|National/) != -1) {
    newPathName = newPathName.split('/').pop();
}
linkhref = newPathName;
```

Comment: Howdy trincot, thanks! Can I pass `'/Executive|District|Division|National/'` into the includes method?
So `if (newPathName.includes('/Executive|District|Division|National/')) {
`

Comment: You can do this: `if (newPathName.search(/Executive|District|Division|National/) != -1)`, but if the only reason is to replace that with nothing, then just do that always, without conditional `if`.

Comment: See paragraph I added to my answer concerning conditional path removal.